# Multiple renders in a wildcard get nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to have a wildcard get function that renders a view based on what is needed (I am using jQuery to call these views).

Here is the code I am trying:

```
app.get('/*.ejs', function(req, res){

  // Actions View
  if (req.xhr) {
    if ('actions') {
      res.render('actions');
    } else if ('profile') {
      res.render('profile');
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('/game');
  }
});
```

I understand that this does no work, and it will always render my actions view, perhaps you can't do it this way to begin with. My question is: am I going about this wrong? I'd rather not create different get functions for each view that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get url parameter from `req.params`, and build your logic regarding to that parameter. For your case, it can be something like this:

```
app.get('/:view.ejs', function(req, res) {
   // Actions View
   if (req.xhr) {
      if (req.params.view === 'actions') {
        res.render('actions');
      } else if (req.params.view === 'profile') {
        res.render('profile');
      }
    } else {
    res.redirect('/game');
   }
});
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! It sucks being new to nodejs/express, I don't half the dang calls and functions :/. But I am curious... why `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: It is always better to do strict comparison(`===` or `!==`), when both sides are of same type.

Comment: Hmm, how interesting. Thank you very much for the help, and tip. :)